# Bind html content to Webview in FlipView Control in Windows Phone 8.1 C# WinRT

Tags: c#, xaml, webview, windows-runtime, windows-phone-8.1

I have a set of records where one of the property contains html content that needs to be displayed in a Flipview Control loading the webview with html content.

How can I Bind or set the html string to WebView control.
WebView has NavigateToString method but in flipview how can I call it for each and every item.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to bind the WebView Source property to a property of the items from the collection that is bound to the FlipView